# Selenium Manager Vs WebDriverMAnager - From selenium 4.6 do we really need WebDriverManager

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java, seleniummanager

I am using WebDriverManager - for Chrome driver - recently after chrome update to 116 was facing issues with WebdriverManager - not able to get ChromeDriver session - Removed WebdriverManager from POM and just used driver = new ChromeDriver(); it worked - Do we need to use WenDriverManager going forward

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();  
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

For Chrome 116 above one should have been worked without any changes - But it failed so I removed `WebdriverManager` (From pom also) and used `driver = new ChromeDriver()`; it worked - SeleniumManager

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium 4.6.0 or above, then you don't need WebDriverManager. Because Selenium has an inbuilt tool to handle drivers. So you don't need WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();